# Communicating with the system under different subnet within a LAN using TCP

Tags: sockets, networking, distributed-system

I have made two programs using socket programming (TCP), one is for the server and the other is for the client.

They are run on two different machines, and I am successful in communicating between them when they are on the same subnet, but I'm unable to communicate when they are on two different subnets. The machines are on the same LAN in both cases.

What is the solution for communicating between machines on two different subnets?

We have tried to change the subnet address of one of the machines to match with the other, which didn't work. We also tried adding an additional IP address, but are stuck in between.

Comment: Is each subnet it’s own router? You could try using some port forwarding on the inside. Subnets will usually have their own NAT schemes, even if they don’t have a firewall that drops packets.

Comment: Communcation between subnetworks of one lan is very similar to communication between several networks on the internet.

Comment: Your program is probably fine. You need to fix the network. If the systems can `ping` each other, then you should be able to communicate with sockets as well. If they can't `ping` each other, then you have a network problem.

Comment: This is not a programming question, but a general network management question. Try asking on [sf] instead.